# ngDraggable not working if dropzone is more and has body scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, drag-and-drop, ngdraggable

According to demo here itself: http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable/blob/master/example.html

Drag and drop is not possible at present using `0.1.11` version.

My code implementation looks as below:

```
            <uib-accordion-group is-open="category.open"
                             name="category-{{category.name}}"
                             ng-drop="true"
                             ng-drop-success="vm.onCategoryDropComplete($index, $data)"
                             ng-repeat="category in vm.categories track by $index">
            <uib-accordion-heading>
                <span style="display: none;">{{catIndex = $index}}</span>
                <div class="main-heading" id="category-name-{{catIndex}}"
                     ng-click="vm.toggleOpen($event, false, category);">
                    <span class="drag-and-drop" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="category">{{category.categoryName}}</span>
                    <span class="text-muted pull-right glyphicon" id="accordion-123"
                          ng-click="vm.toggleOpen($event, true, category);"
                          ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': category.open,
                            'glyphicon-chevron-right': !category.open}" aria-hidden="true">
                    </span>
                </div>
            </uib-accordion-heading>
        </uib-accordion-group>
```

I see somechanges has happened in 0.1.12 version, need its implementation example and also i am not able to download as its throwing error as the version 0.1.12 is not available.

[image]

Please refer the image below:
http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable/blob/master/example.html

Please find the plunkr link fore more info: http://plnkr.co/edit/BmTkM96CeelEa2Uml5Vz?p=preview

Not able to drop at last Dropzones from the above plunker.

Is there any alternative quick solution to overcome from it or am i missing the usability from the ngDraggable plugin itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve by adding `ng-drag-scroll verticalScroll="true"` to use this on your draggable elements

Here is the updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/IWym7S3T0NwtInQRLjzJ?p=preview

Comment: I've got similar problem, but mu drop area is inside container with position abosolute. It seems that the scrollbar moves but the page does not scroll